# Mathematical Definition of "Smoothness" : Requirement of Differentiable Functions to be Smooth?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, smooth-functions

I have often heard the following arguments made about the requirement for differentiable functions to be smooth:

- Fractal Functions are nowhere smooth
- Differentiable functions need to be smooth
- Therefore, differentiable functions need to be smooth

I tried to find a formal definition of smoothness that provides some sort of "checklist" - for instance, if "conditions a,b,c" are met then the function is smooth else not smooth. But when reading links such as this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness), I could not find any such "checklist" for definitions of smoothness and differentiability of functions.

As a particular example, consider the popular example of the Weierstrass Function - this function is said to be:

- Nowhere smooth
- A continuous Function
- A Fractal Function
- Nowhere differentiable

Yet the main argument ([https://math.berkeley.edu/~brent/files/104_weierstrass.pdf](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ebrent/files/104_weierstrass.pdf)
) I keep coming across that shows why the Weierestrass Function is not differentiable does not seem to directly rely on the absence of "smoothness" :

[image]

It seems like the non-differentiability of this function is established using Properties of Calculus, **and not using smoothness?** The above proof shows that the derivative of the Weierstrass Function is equal to "infinity" everywhere - therefore does not exist.

- But could a proof have been made that "directly demonstrates that the Weierstrass  function is non-differentiable because it is not smooth"?
- Can we show that the Weierstrass function is not smooth?

**Can someone please comment on the explicit relationship between smoothness of a function and differentiability? Is there some result/theorem that demonstrates the requirement of differentiable functions to be smooth? How do we mathematically quantify the "smoothness" of a function?**

Thanks!

Comment: What do you understand by "smooth"? In general, "smooth function" means $C^k$ function, for some $k$ which varies with the context

Comment: Smooth usually means $C^1$ or $C^{\infty},$ but as @Danilo Gregorin Afonso points out, it can also mean other things. For another example, there's [*Smooth functions*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-12/issue-1/Smooth-functions/10.1215/S0012-7094-45-01206-3.short) by Zygmund (1945), a notion that usually now goes by the name "Zygmund smooth" or some other name besides simply "smooth". For what it's worth, my Ph.D. dissertation showed (as one of several results) that "most" continuous functions are nowhere Zygmund smooth for a rather strong notion of "most".

Comment: Bullet points two and three in the first group say the same thing...? In any case, the common usage of _smooth_ implies _differentiable_, but (as Danilo and Dave note) a smooth function has _continuous derivative_, and may also entail existence of _derivatives of all orders_. Particularly, we can't prove a function is non-differentiable by proving the function is non-smooth. <> The checklist for "class $C^k$" is: The first derivative exists and is continuous, the second derivative exists and is continuous, ..., the $k$th derivative exists and is continuous.